# Demonstrate an inequality

Tags: inequality

For $a>0$, $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}$

$$|x|<\frac1a,|y|<\frac1a,|z|<\frac1a$$

demonstrate that:

$$\frac{|(x+y)|}{|1+a^2xy|}<\frac1a$$
My work:
$$-\frac1a<\frac{x+y}{1+a^2x}<\frac1a$$
$$|x|<\frac1a \implies -\frac1a<x<\frac1a  |ax|<1  $$
$$|y|<\frac1a \implies -\frac1a<y<\frac1a  |ay|<1$$
$$|z|<\frac1a \implies -\frac1a<z<\frac1a  |az|<1$$

$$|a^2xy|<1 => -1<a^2xy<1$$
 $$|a^2xz|<1 => -1<a^2xz<1$$
$$ |a^2yz|<1 => -1<a^2yz<1$$

What is the next step? Please help me!!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some reductions that might help:

1. Set $s = ax$, $t = ay$. Now we must show $s,t \in (-1,1)$ implies $|s+t| < |1 + st|$.
2. Since $s,t \in (-1,1)$, $|1 + st| = 1 + st$.

Now try to prove the inequality $|s + t| < 1 + st$, in the way you have in your attempted answer. (Don't forget $-1 < s,t < 1$!)